# Compression to Elasticsearch indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, compression

Is there a way to set default compression method to best_compression with newly created indexes in Elasticsearch?

Obviously it can be done manually after index has been created.

Based on googling, this should be achievable either by setting it in elasticsearch.yml, or by creating a custom template to set it. However, I haven't been able to get it right in elasticsearch.yml. I've tried all sorts of variations, but basically this should do it:

```
index.codec: best_compression
```

But it doesn't.

I'm also not comfortable with creating a custom template, since my goal is to get this compression to all indexes, not just those created using some specific template. But if it's the only way, so be it.

My use case is Elasticsearch with Logstash, so Logstash is the creator of these indexes. Without custom templates, setting the compression method in Logstash configs seems completely impossible.  I'm running Elasticsearch version 2.2.0.

Currently I can set the compression manually just fine after closing index and executing:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/example_index/_settings' -d '{"index":{"codec":"best_compression"}}'
```

And then reopening the index.

From official documentation:

```
index.codec
```

> The default value compresses stored data with LZ4 compression, but
>   this can be set to best_compression which uses DEFLATE for a higher
>   compression ratio, at the expense of slower stored fields performance.

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html

Answer (score 5):

The `index.codec` setting is a node level setting and it won't be visible in the list of settings for a new index. If the index template is **specifically** setting the `codec` then that one will be used, otherwise the one at node level will be.

Also, when changing the codec for an index, only the new segments (after new indexing, changes to existent documents or segments merging) will use the new codec.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware that the codec change isn't retroactive, but it really hadn't even occurred to me that the changed codec won't show in index settings if it's done on node-level.

But yes, it does show in node settings visible with:

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes?pretty=true'`

So thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

`index.codec` is a [static setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/index-modules.html)   , it can not be modified on live index. You can change this by using [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html).

Answer (score 0):

A bit of hacky way to do it if you don't want to do it on node-level, you can set up a template which has `*` as its index pattern. Example:

```
PUT _template/my_template
{
  "index_patterns": ["*"],
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "codec": "best_compression"
    }
  }
}
```